# Android Studio Google Maps Key

Tags: android

SOS,

I am working on an Android project that entails using the Google Maps API.  I have generated a key with the proper restrictions but I cannot get my program to run.  The error I am getting is:

> Error:(53, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/google_maps_key').

I did some research and found that I needed to change `@string/google_maps_key` to my actual key.  See the example below.  Take note of the fact the tags are emitted.

Before:

```
meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" /
```

After:

```
meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBY3c7RFvwzs06juEg0nzIU7PVERTIV3U8" /
```

I attempted to make the changes shown but when I run my program is automatically changes it back to `@string/google_maps_key`.

What must I do to get my mapping application up and running?  Thank you in advance to anybody with helpful input.

Comment: Go into your `strings.xml` file and change the `google_maps_key` resource to your key

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is **navigate to - res/values/strings.xml** in your android app project and change your file to something like this:

Under `<resources>` you may have many more strings just add the one shown here too and it will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key">AIzaSyBY3c7RFvwzs06juEg0nzIU7PVERTIV3U8</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Awesome. Do consider accepting the answer by clicking on tick if this helped you out solving the issue :) . Good luck

Comment: Awesome, nothing is mentioned in this google tutorial :( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker

Comment: I have the `google_maps_api key` defined in
`src/deub/res/values/google_maps_api.xml`
as well as `src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml`.  I have run the release build on my device and i can see the map rendering, however I am using `Bitrise.io` for continuous integration and its giving me the following error :
```
> Android resource linking failed
  /Users/etiennelawlor/workspace/sampleapp/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/compileOptions/AndroidManifest.xml:48: AAPT: error: resource string/google_maps_key (aka com.sampleapp:string/google_maps_key) not found.
```

Comment: @toobsco42 ofcourse you can have any file name as long as your string resources map to _R.string_ check if that is the case try using the convection too. Sometimes external libs are designed to read convention files like strings.xml etc

Comment: What is convection?

Comment: @toobsco42 By convention* I meant putting all your strings resources in strings.xml just like the example shared in answer above

Comment: It's as if you can't have release and debug variant strings

Comment: @toobsco42 well.. I was trying to say something else! anyway regarding the issue I can't be sure about how you are saving the key unless I see the file. But what I really wanna ask you is are you using this: in your string resources file where you set the api key ?  *templateMergeStrategy="preserve"*

Comment: Yep i'm using that property `templateMergeStrategy="preserve"`

Comment: This solution isn't working for me in the current AS, version 3.4. A generated.xml file keeps getting created and I get the duplicate key error. Adding the key to the strings.xml file or any other resource file (like google_maps_api.xml) doesn't work. I can't find what in the project or Android Studio is causing generated.xml to be generated. Google searches turn up answers like this one. What's creating generated.xml?